# Implement load more button in material-table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I have been working with material table....
code for sample table: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-86e7g?file=/demo.js

Sample table O/P looks like below image

[image]

I want to add load more button, such that it looks like the image below:

[image]

Onclick of load more button, it loads rest of the data.

I don't want how load more loads rest of the data, I just want to have this load more button in material-table.

I tried looking for the solution, but was unable to find anything for this table.

If anyone has worked on it or need any further information, please do let me know.

Comment: The feature you want to implement is pagination and it's already supported if you saw the bottom right corner.

Comment: No no....its not about pagination. Since I have very large data set it takes time to load all of the data. So I want to limit data to be let's say 100 and if user wants to load all of the data they can click on load more and fetch all of the data. So usage for pagination and load more button for me is different.

Comment: You can limit no rows in the current picture it's 5 but you can change those values I guess about 20 is supported and you can also make it custom also.

Comment: I think I was not clear, see when I fetch from API it returns me all of the data in DB which is a large set of data, but I want to set limit to , let's say 100, so at a time only 100 data will load, now when I add show more button in the table, user can load all of the remaining data. When talking about pagination, since all of the data is fetched from API, so the loading time still remains the same and once it has been loaded then I can set how many data I can view at a time. So, that is why I'm looking for load more button, so I can limit how many data to fetch at start.

Comment: Did you solved this? I also want to add a load more button (maybe as additional row) to fetch more data from the server. This is actually a UX thing, our customers won't understand that the can load more with the next page button.

Answer (score 0):

For Server side pagination, you can use the remote data feature as the [doc](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data)  suggested.

Comment: Could be just a comment

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30751302)